On certain pages, encountering a TypeError: 'google.maps.places' is undefined. It functions correctly on the home page
Encountering a problem with the Google Maps Places API: it functions correctly on the home page, but throws a TypeError 'google.maps.places' is undefined on certain other pages. Upon inspecting the console, no additional errors are found.
Here is my code.
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY') }}&loading=async&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function initAutocomplete() {
                $('.map-location').each(async(index, input) => {

                    var autocomplete = await new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                        if (!place.geometry) {
                            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                            return;
                        }
                        var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                        $('input[name="latitude"]').val(latitude);
                        $('input[name="longitude"]').val(longitude);
                        console.log("Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude);
                    });
                });
            }

            initAutocomplete();
        });
    </script>

On some pages, when I try to retrieve latitude and longitude based on search autofill in the Google Maps Places API for an input field named "location", I encounter an issue. While it functions correctly on the home page, on other pages, it throws a TypeError stating that 'google.maps.places' is undefined.

is this code added for all other pages? or is it available only on the home page? also, put function code outside of $(document).ready(function(){

The code is added for all other pages. tried with function code outside of $(document).ready(function(){ but still same error showing

If you use the console to inspect network traffic and errors during loading do you get errors regarding no callback? You are manually invoking your initAutocomplete rather than relying upon Google Maps api to do that when it is fully loaded and ready

The same code is working on my home page. without using callback.

@ANASMK it means your home page has something extra (code) to support this to work.
